# Eigenvalues of masked array (NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas

How can I compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a masked NumPy array (for an unmasked array, this can be achieved by `scipy.linalg.eig`).

---

### Edit:

Turns out you can do this after all.

```
# a list of numpy matrices
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as npma

import numpy.matlib as npm
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg as splin

import pandas as pd

# read in numpy data
import urllib
dataURL = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/arrhythmia.data'
dataFile = urllib.urlopen(dataURL)

# read in the data as a NumPy dataset
aArr = np.genfromtxt(dataFile, dtype = np.float,
                         delimiter = ',', missing_values = '?')

aArrMasked = npma.masked_array(aArr, np.isnan(aArr))
aArrMaskedCenter = aArrMasked - npma.mean(aArrMasked, axis=0)
print splin.eig(npma.cov(aArrMaskedCenter))
```

Comment: that's not defined -- what is the shape of your masked array??

Comment: If you have answered your own question you should submit it as an answer, rather than edit the question.